# Wordpress. Make the entire div class clickable

Tags: html, class, clickable

I'm creating my website on Wordpress: https://imriga.com/

I would like to make a certain div class clickable and always linking to my full blog post. In my case it's the class of the entire blog post snippet which is "wmle_item" (Chrome browser inspect). At the moment only featured image and title are clickable. My goal is to make the entire frame clickable and also add some effects on hover via CSS.

I guess I need to write some function in functions.php?

Comment: _I guess I need to write some function in functions.php?_ - Yes, you probably do. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to make changes only in interactivity (without modifying the current theme or PHP backend) you could use a plugin to include javascript code in the header or footer (for example, https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/)

Then you could add some dynamic features to the content using a simple Javascript code like this (to enable click in the item):

```
<script>
var items=document.querySelectorAll(".wmle_item");
items.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item);
  item.addEventListener("click",function(ev){
     // click event listener
     var link=item.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     link.click();
  })
});
</script>
<style>
.wmle_item{
    cursor: pointer; 
    /*any other customization here */
}
</style>
```

You can test the javascript code in the browser console window on your site.